# ORA-04091: table CISTU018.TIMESHEET is mutating, trigger/function may not see it

Tags: oracle

I have created a trigger:(my before trigger worked well, but my instructor wanted me to do an after trigger, but it didn't work when I tried to fire the trigger)

```
/*AFTER TRIGGER*/
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
SET VERIFY OFF
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER HOUR_TIMESHEET
AFTER INSERT ON TIMESHEET
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
T_REGHOURS TIMESHEET.REGHOURS%TYPE := :NEW.REGHOURS;
T_OTIMEHOURS TIMESHEET.OTIMEHOURS%TYPE := :NEW.REGHOURS - 40;
T_EMPID TIMESHEET.EMPID%TYPE := :NEW.EMPID;
T_PAYWEEKENDDATE TIMESHEET.PAYWEEKENDDATE%TYPE := :NEW.PAYWEEKENDDATE;
BEGIN
  IF(T_REGHOURS > 40)
  THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Employee ID:'|| T_EMPID);
  UPDATE TIMESHEET
    SET REGHOURS = 40, OTIMEHOURS = (T_OTIMEHOURS) WHERE EMPID = :OLD.EMPID AND PAYWEEKENDDATE = :OLD.PAYWEEKENDDATE;
  END IF;
END;

/*end of trigger*/
```

Script output:  the trigger compiled: Trigger HOUR_TIMESHEET compiled

Then I tried to do an insert in order to fire the trigger:
INSERT INTO TIMESHEET VALUES(72690,'30-MAY-03',42,0);

Then it gave me an error message:

```
Error starting at line : 142 in command -
INSERT INTO TIMESHEET VALUES(72690,'30-MAY-03',42,0)
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-04091: table CISTU018.TIMESHEET is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "CISTU018.HOUR_TIMESHEET", line 10
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'CISTU018.HOUR_TIMESHEET'
04091. 00000 -  "table %s.%s is mutating, trigger/function may not see it"
*Cause:    A trigger (or a user defined plsql function that is referenced in
           this statement) attempted to look at (or modify) a table that was
           in the middle of being modified by the statement which fired it.
*Action:   Rewrite the trigger (or function) so it does not read that table.
Employee ID:72690
```

Comment: Thanks ChProgrammer. This error is occurring because you are not allowed inside a row-level trigger to update (to select) the same table the trigger is attached to.  I'll post an example how to deal with this restriction, but it would be good to understand more of what you are trying to do with this trigger. The trigger makes updates based on :OLD values, but in an INSERT statement, :OLD is always NULL. Should this be :NEW instead, or did you want to fire this trigger after update rather than insert?

Comment: ChProgrammer an example has been added that coerces surplus reghours to otimehours, but wasn't 100% this is the goal.  If this isn't the intent, please let me know and update the question with a little more background.  Thanks

Comment: @alexgibbs, thank you very much for your response. The following was the question:                                                                                          #5. Write a trigger for the timesheet table that detects if a number greater than 40 is inserted for reghours in a payperiod, and if it is, places 40 in the hours worked column and calculates the ot hours for the new record. #

Comment: @alexgibbs It is why the error message is confusing me. The goal of the trigger is to prevent the insert or update of the timesheet table for any regular hour more than 40h. So once it detects the insert or update to make the regular hour more than 40, the trigger will update the row to make the regular hour equals 40 hours and ot hour = regular hour - 40. if I am not allowed to update or select the same table the trigger is attached to, there would be no point of the trigger at all.

Answer (score 0):

The update statement in the body of the row-level `TRIGGER` is forbidden, as it reads from the `TABLE` to which the trigger is attached.  Any `SELECT` or manipulation of the attached table is prohibited in oracle row-level triggers.
If your goal is to convert surplus (>40) regular-hours in new `TIMESHEET` records to overtime-hours, you don't need to make an update in the statement at all and can use a `BEFORE` `TRIGGER` to directly mutate incoming data, but as you mentioned your instructor asked for an `AFTER TRIGGER`, I'll include an `AFTER` example.    I'm not sure if this is a suggestion or a requirement, so I'll include a little discussion about `BEFORE` triggers as well, as these may be preferable, depending on the situation.

Here's a simple example using an `AFTER` trigger, presuming there aren't other triggers involved.  In this example, the `TRIGGER` timing is changed to statement rather than `ROW`.  This removes the restriction you observed in your original error, and pulls any surplus hours away from regular-hours and adds them to overtime-hours.

First, create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE  TIMESHEET(
EMPID NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL,
REGHOURS NUMBER(3,0) NOT NULL,
OTIMEHOURS NUMBER(3,0) NOT NULL,
PAYWEEKENDDATE DATE NOT NULL);
```

Then create the statement-level `AFTER` `TRIGGER`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER HOUR_TIMESHEET
AFTER INSERT ON TIMESHEET
BEGIN
UPDATE TIMESHEET
SET REGHOURS = 40,
OTIMEHOURS = (OTIMEHOURS + REGHOURS - 40)
WHERE REGHOURS > 40;
END;
/
```

Then test it by inserting some data:

```
--reghours <= 40 and no overtime present. No change expected
INSERT INTO TIMESHEET VALUES (1,40, 0, TO_DATE('20170401','YYYYMMDD'));
-- reghours < 40 and overtime already counted.  No change expected
INSERT INTO TIMESHEET VALUES (2,20, 15, TO_DATE('20170401','YYYYMMDD'));
-- reghours (50) > 40, plus 10 additional overtime hours.  Expecting adjustment to 40 + 20
INSERT INTO TIMESHEET VALUES (1,50, 10, TO_DATE('20170415','YYYYMMDD'));
-- reghours (55) > 40, plus no overtime.  Expecting adjustment to 40 + 15
INSERT INTO TIMESHEET VALUES (2,55, 0, TO_DATE('20170415','YYYYMMDD'));
COMMIT;
```

Then check what the TRIGGER did:

```
SELECT * FROM TIMESHEET ORDER BY 4 ASC, 1 ASC;
EMPID  REGHOURS  OTIMEHOURS  PAYWEEKENDDATE
1      40        0           01-APR-17
2      20        15          01-APR-17
1      40        20          15-APR-17
2      40        15          15-APR-17
```

The trigger swept through `AFTER` the `INSERT` completed, and updated surplus `REGHOURS` to `OTIMEHOURS`, but left other `REGHOURS` and `OTIMEHOURS` alone.  Hopefully this aligns with your goals.

There are pros and cons to the use of row-level and statement-level triggers, and deciding what to use can depend on the data model involved as well as other triggers in play, etc.
Another alternative is to just use a `BEFORE` trigger to directly mutate the values of incoming `:NEW` fields, as you mentioned in your question.  Please keep in mind that this may be lower-cost and preferable, depending on the data involved and whether other `TRIGGER`s are in-play. Weighing pros and cons of statement vs row can be beneficial.

Keeping triggers as simple as possible is recommended.  However, if you really need to take action that would make use of selecting against the attached-table and require row-level evaluations, or need to tune or nuance statement-level triggers,  I'd recommend looking into [Compound-Triggers](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#LNPLS2005)

Comment: it worked, and it is so simple , thank you so much. but I still want to know why I the statement level trigger worked but row trigger won't work. also , if I want to write a trigger working on the update (might be many rows),would this work as well. I will try it later. and thank you so much,

Comment: Thanks @ChProgrammer The statement-level trigger works because it is reading the table after it has finished mutating all involved rows--the statement has settled and another can begin anew with a fresh committed read and new statement serialization.  Selecting what type of trigger to use (if any) depends on the situation.  A statement-trigger that is valid for an insert may need to be changed or replaced with another type to work reliably for an update, etc. especially if multiple triggers are in play.  Sometimes the best trigger is none at all.

Comment: @ChProgrammer Did you have a specific update situation in mind--were you looking to directly change from an insert to an insert/update or were you looking at something else?  Adding updates or multiple triggers might be getting away from the context for this post, but can be explored more thoroughly in another question.

Comment: thank you very much. now I understand why it won't get the error for the statement level trigger.

Comment: what if I want to have a trigger fired by update the timesheet: if the regular hour has been updated to over 40, then fire the trigger to make it 40 and the over hour to be ot hour. (for example 42-- reg hour 40 and ot hour +=2). I am concerning, because the trigger is fired by update, and the trigger itself is an update statement, would it be fired over and over and never stop

Comment: @ChProgrammer Your concern about uncontrolled/unexpected behavior is well-placed.  Runaway triggers are indeed possible and appropriate planning is necessary to avoid; in fact, Oracle has errors to throw when it detects runaways (like ORA-00036).  It may be worthwhile to try swapping `AFTER INSERT` for `AFTER UPDATE` to see what happens when you update the table.  I'd add an example here, but want to keep the answer in-line with the original question.  To explore `UPDATE` questions more, I'd recommend closing this question and asking a new one.

Comment: @ChProgrammer `TRIGGER`s are no different than other code--selecting the correct `TRIGGER` (or none) for the situation and planning for their interactions and downstream effects makes all the difference.  In a real-world scenario, an after `TRIGGER` that mutates it's attached table would likely not be considered since `BEFORE` triggers align better with mutating incoming data.  But the truth is, triggers (of any type) can often be skipped entirely, when simple `CONSTRAINT`s can ensure the data (eg timesheet) is correct instead.  Thanks

Comment: thank you very much. I think I will use before trigger to solve the update trigger problems.